# JHipster - Docker-compose - enable SSL

Tags: docker, spring-boot, https, docker-compose, jhipster

I'm trying to get SSL working on my JHipster app.

I'm using docker and docker-compose, and have the following:

**app.yml**

```
ports:
        - 443:443
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ADD /keystore.p12 /keystore.p12
EXPOSE 443
```

**application-prod.yml**

```
server:
    port: 443
    ssl:
        key-store: /keystore.p12
        key-store-password: <password>
        keyStoreType: PKCS12
        keyAlias: <alias>
```

I generated a self certified key via `keytool -genkey` as mentioned in `application-prod.yml` and copied  this (using ADD DockerFile) into the app image. (I'm aware this probably isn't best practice ~ but it is for dev purposes).

`./mvnw package -Pprod docker:build` and then `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up` runs without error.

When I try to connect via https://localhost:443 I get connection refused.

I should mention when the ssl entry is removed from `application-prod.yml` everything works as expected i.e. site loads ok in http.

Thanks,

Comment: What are the logs when you run with ssl entries in prod? Can you post the logs to your question?

Comment: https://localhost:443 this is wrong,  use only  https://localhost

Comment: I suggest to use nginx, with proxy passing the server

Comment: @JinnaBalu re: nginx, will be looking at that solution going forward. Thanks

Comment: @TarunLalwani I regenerated the keystore.p12 and it works now, hurrah. I could not find in the log files where this issue would have been highlighted which was a bit annoying. Assuming somewhere with the embedded Tomcat instance of the container..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading in the comments, this was a user misconfiguration...

Comment: Yes it was. Thanks Julien.